# StackOverflowError while using Scala Iterator

Tags: scala, io, stack-overflow

I am trying to save a large data set (50MB) into file. But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:350)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:350)
...
```

It looks to me like a recursion problem but I can't find where it would come from. Plase help. Function that makes the Iterator[String]:

```scala
override def toJsonIterator: Iterator[String] = {

  val lastId = listMap.keys.toList.sorted.last

  def evalJS(id: Int): String = {
    Json.prettyPrint(listMap(id).toJsonValue) + (if(id != lastId) "," else "")
  }

  listMap.keys.toList.sorted
    .foldLeft(Iterator("{"))( (sum, id) => sum ++ Iterator(evalJS(id)) ) ++ Iterator("}")
}
```

The save to file code:

```scala
private def write(st: Iterator[String], file: String): Unit = {
  if (st.isEmpty) return ()
  val f = new File(file)
  if (!f.getParentFile().exists()) f.getParentFile().mkdirs()
  if (!f.exists()) f.createNewFile()
  val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
  try {
    while(st.hasNext) {
      p.println(st.next())
    }
  }
  catch {
    case e:Exception => println("Error: could not write to file \""+file+"\" because: "+e)
  }
  finally { p.close() }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug with scala 2.10, see [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2323). Any alternatives?

Comment: What's the stack trace in your code? Could it be one of the lines where you force the iterator to evaluate to List?

Comment: The stack trace is shown above, where ... is for repetition. Could you clarify what you mean with second statement, please?